# Web components - what's the difference between shadow host and shadow root?

Tags: html

I was reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) article about Web Components from MDN.

After looking at the DOM shadow terminology and its diagram, I wondered how are the shadow host and the shadow root different. Aren't they the same node in the graph in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple just think of what the words means

**host:** Something (house) that holds something else (people), you can say that the house is hosting the people.

In a Web Component context `host` means the element you attached the shadow to.

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
let shadow = div.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
```

The `attachShadow` function returns a `DocumentFragment` [<sup>ref</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)  which is our shadow root, and the div is the host for the shadow element.

## Demo

```js
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id="the host"
let shadow = div.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

console.log(shadow.host)
console.log(shadow.constructor.name)
```